# pandas add() two dataframes with parcially overlapping indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

**Python/Pandas**

So I have *n* many dataframes consisting of only 3 columns as follows:

```
02-10-2017 09:00:00, 0, 2.23, -2.24
02-10-2017 09:01:00, 0, 2.23, -2.23
...
```

with the datetime being the index (of the format DatetimeIndex).

Now every dataframe has *m* many indexes/rows and every dataframe starts a specific amount of time after the other.

For example dataframe 1 is from 02-10-2017 09:00 until 02-10-2017 15:00 and dataframe 2 from 02-10-2017 10:00 until 02-10-2017 16:00. I want to add these such that I have one dataframe from 09:00 until 16:00 with added values.

The closest function I found is [pandas.add()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add), however, when I add two dataframes then the non-coinciding indexes get value NaN.

So in my example that would mean NaN values from 09:00 until 10:00 and from 15:00 until 16:00. Suggestions?

Comment: You've not stated what you want as the values for the missing time indices, you can interpolate, put a default value, mean, etc.. Can you add some sample data and the desired output

Comment: @EdChum there are no missing time indices only some that do not exist in both dataframes.

Comment: Okay so now I added this in my script and I get "fill_value 0 not supported" ? df = df.add(df2, fill_value=0)

Comment: What version of pandas are you running as that has been supported for a long time

Comment: I'm running pandas 0.22.0 through Anaconda/jupyter lab. But it's specifically weird because I made another example where it did work and then I implemented in the mainframe and it didn't.

Comment: Don't know is `df` really a Pandas dataframe? what does `type(df)` show?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: try restarting your kernel, it should work I can't explain it

Comment: Hmmm I've seen something that hints towards some sort of error, if I delete fill_value and just roll with it. I get a dataframe of size i times j. instead of j times 1. with i being the rownumber of the first df

Comment: Yep I found it. Turns out that in `df = df.add(df2,fill_value=0)` I had df2 as a series since I selected one column from a df. So I just switched df = pd.Series(data=..) :) Thanks aa lot anyhow Ed!

Answer (score 3):

I just found it actually. The NaN values do not stem from non-coinciding indexes but from

`x (from df1) + NaN (from df2) = NaN`

The fill_value option can set the NaN values of one dataframe equal to any specified value. In my case `fill_value=0` solved the problem.

Comment: In case you get the fill_value=0 error, make sure that you add a dataframe to a dataframe and a series to a series.